How to prevent rows from being added to the DataGridView when we click the ToolStripButton
I have ToolStripButton1.Click, when I click on it, the row is added. I don't want this to happen
See the problem here

Public Class Form2
    Dim myTable As New DataTable()
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        myTable.Columns.Add("Name")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myTable
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'No Problem
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = Not DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows
    End Sub
    Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
        'But This Event Problem?
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = Not DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows
    End Sub
End Class

I want to set the AllowUserToAddRows variable true or false with the ToolStripButton1.Click event

I think this can be a good solution
 Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
  'New Solution
   DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Nothing 'To remove focus
   DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = Not DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows
  End Sub

